# Sitecore content editor not always asks to update broken links

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, broken-links, content-editor

I have a problem regarding broken links in Sitecore.

Our tree is filled by a console application with data from an other, older cms through the **Sitecore item API**.

We have products that are linked to Categories with a **multilist**. When an editor deletes a category, sitecore should give a popup to handle the **broken links**. This he does in 1 of the 4 cases. In the other cases Sitecore does not give a popup and the category deleted still appears in the multilist as *"Not in the selection list"*.

Is there something wrong with how we insert the items or is it just Sitecore not being able to handle large amounts of data in the linking story?

FYI: we have around 160 categories and more than 1200 products.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild your `Links Database` from the Sitecore `Control Panel -> Database` application?

Comment: I will give that a go and post my findings. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marek Musielak 's comment did the trick. Rebuilding the Links Database is the best way to ensure no broken links.